# JavaScript Closures Manipulation

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm doing some Node.js and I want to use the closure representation to create my objects. I think I'm missing something, because something simple like this isn't working:

```
var Room = function(foo) {
    this.name = foo;
    this.users= [];
    return {
        getName : function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
var room = new Room("foo");
console.log(room.getName());
```

I also have tried without the parameter.. and still not working.

```
var Room = function() {
    this.name = "foo";
    this.users= [];
    return {
        getName : function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
var room = new Room();
console.log(room.getName());
```

However, something like this works:

```
var Room = function(foo) {
    this.name = foo;
    this.users= [];
}
var room = new Room("foo");
console.log(room.name);
```

I can't understand why this isn't working.

--Edited

Thanks to Amadan I have found the right way to do it:

```
var Room = function() {
    var name = "foo";
    var users= [];
    return {
        getName : function() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
var room = new Room();
console.log(room.getName());
```

This way "name" and "users" are encapsulated.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that `new Room() instanceof Room === false` with this approach.

Comment: Hard to say really, probably not too bad on the whole. The kind of thing that could eventually lead to some obscure bug or possibly prevent you from doing something... a lot of uses of `instanceof` end up being antipatterns anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` in a constructor will overwrite `this`. So the right way to do this is:

```
var Room = function(foo) {
    this.name = foo;
    this.users= [];
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

or

```
var Room = function(foo) {
    return {
        name: "foo",
        users: [],
        getName : function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

The first one does everything on the original `this`; the second one replaces `this` with everything you need.

Comment: Thanks man. Your question helped me to find the right way to do it. I wanted to encapsulate those fields.